# Call to undefined function sqlite_open

Tags: php

Searched already on many sites with no results. PHP keeps on saying:

```
Call to undefined function sqlite_open()
```

If I manually load sqlite (it's already installed with `yum install php-pdo`) I get

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in /home/kpark/dbconnect.php on line 9
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server since installing `php-pdo`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`sqlite_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php) was the function in the sqlite2 extension. What you've installed is probably the [sqlite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php) module, which requires `sqlite3::open()` instead.

But you should not use the native interface either way. Use PDO to open sqlite databases. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

Comment: I was going to upvote you but... *"But you should not use the native interface either way."* That's one's opinion. There's no reason not to use it if you know what you're doing. Even though I support PDO, I don't think this should be put as a fact, because there's nothing wrong with the native interface. :)

Comment: @netcoder: Well depends. The native interfaces for Oracle or DB2 certainly provide heaps of custom features. But in this case, the sqlite3 class offers nothing over PDO, it just feels like API divergency. But true, that's also mostly preference.

Comment: why cant we just use version 2. what is the problem in it? i dont like all these :: and pdo for my simple process. cause i maintain a very simple database for a very simple purpose and all these pdo things overloads me why cant things be simple instead of keep wrapping and wrapping in the name of oops. i am talking this only for this context and not other concepts for which i really rely on OOPS. oops.

Comment: @JayapalChandran You can keep using the sqlite2 interface, but need to recompile it on newer servers. The advantage of the SQLite3 format is robustness and more features. That it only comes in OOP flavour in PHP is a design decision of the php.net maintainer. I understand eschewing elaborate syntax. But really OOP is nothing more than a notation. You can write object-oriented code using just procedures/functions. And likewise the sqlite3:: interface is quite procedural still. PDO is a bit more elaborate, but the way to go because you can easily switch between different database servers later.

Comment: @mario oh ok. i understand. yet, you have mentioned not to use native and instead to use PDO. any special mentions...