# How to configure sqlite2 & 3 in php 5.3.6 on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, sqlite

How can I configure sqlite2 and sqlite3, both in PHP 5.3.6 on Ubuntu 11.10?

I work on two PHP projects: one uses sqlite2, and another uses sqlite3. I am working on Ubuntu 11.10. My problem is that my sqlite2 code does not run; it gives the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()`. I want to run both code.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the necessary PHP module loaded. Have you tried `php -m` to check?

Comment: Maybe useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788853/call-to-undefined-function-sqlite-open

Comment: @halfer Thanks but my requirement is that i want run both code sqlite2 and sqlite3. I have tried php -m command its display sqlite3 in list but does not display sqlite2 so how to support both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by read the solution given on below link

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/875262

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to determine what version is available in PHP, and then use the correct function accordingly. I am assuming from your comment that sqlite modules will appear as "sqlite" or "sqlite3" in the extensions list (I don't use them myself).

```
$sqlite2 = extension_loaded('sqlite');
$sqlite3 = extension_loaded('sqlite3');
if (!$sqlite2 && !$sqlite3)
{
    die('Neither extension loaded');
}

if ($sqlite2)
{
    // Use sqlite_open()
}
else
{
    // Use sqlite3::open()
}
```

You may wish to write some shortcut functions, so you don't have to put the version checks in your code.

Comment: As per your code every time goes in else means there is no driver available for sqlite2 Am i right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. My code approach is: if the sqlite2 interface is available in PHP, it probably means that sqlite2 is installed on the machine; if the sqlite3 interface is available, it probably means that sqlite3 is installed on the machine.

Comment: Ah... do you want to run versions 2 and 3 at the same time?

Comment: No I have work on different project 1 is used sqlite2 and another in sqlite3.I have configure php for sqlite3 support after configuration support only sqlite3 instead of both.

Comment: So, in other words, you want "sqlite2" and "sqlite3" to appear in `php -m`? If so, tell us _in your question_ how you are reconfiguring PHP. Are you recompiling it with the necessary flags, or just modifying your php.ini?

Comment: (Also, it may be that sqlite2 is not available for 5.3.6 - another approach, which is desirable anyway, is to upgrade your sqlite2 project to sqlite3!)

Comment: I think the first line should be: $sqlite2 = extension_loaded('sqlite');
to check if sqlite extension is available.

Comment: @David, I think you may be right. I only have `sqlite3` in my current PHP build, so that one looks OK.

Comment: I have tested it and it is: `$sqlite2 = extension_loaded('sqlite');`
Maybe you should change it in your answer. All in all, I think this is a very good way to evaluate which sqlite db is used.

Comment: @David, done and thanks. I believe you can edit things here too, and you are welcome to - however under 3K rep requires going through the review queue.