# SQLite to php connection trouble

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I kinda desperately need help with this...

I've been working on this project for hours only to hit a wall that I just can't get over.

I made a small database that I created using an sql manager from firefox, and the database does contain data and has a .sqlite extension. But not matter what I try looking at other people's questions and the answers, I just can't get it to work. Every time I think I've got it it throws a new error.

Does anyone think they could help me pinpoint the problem? I've been going at this for so long and I'm so frustrated at this point I don't know what to do anymore. I'm running my site through XAMPP and receive this error from the PHP:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\FinalProject\You_Shall_Pass.php on line 4
```

I attempted to edit XAMPP's php.ini to support sqlite, but it's still not connecting, and I've changed the connection method a few times now with no results other than a slight change in error.

If anyone can help, I can't even tell you how grateful I am. I'm at my wits end with this project, and my book doesn't really seem to explain anywhere how to connect to an sqlite file.

Code:

```
<?php

// Open database
$dbHandle = sqlite_open('YSP_db.sqlite', 0666, $error);

if(!$dbhandle) die ($error);

//Method selects function for login or new account procedure
if(isset($_POST['profileName']))
{
    getUserData();
}
elseif(isset($_POST['newProfileName']))
{
    createNewUser();
}
else {echo "why god why?";}

function getUserData()
{
    $login = $_POST['profileName'];
    $rows = $dsn->query("SELECT idUser FROM user WHERE name = '$login'");
}



?>
```

UPDATE: Switching my database file extension to db from sqlite and opening it through sqlite3 as was suggested below got rid of the error, but now I have two new ones:
Undefined variable: db on line 29 and

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object line 29
```

I also attempted to open the database through a class as an alternative, so it now looks like this:

```
?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->open('YSP_db.db');
}
}

// Open database
$db = new MyDB();

if(!$db) die ($error);

//Method selects function for login or new account procedure
if(isset($_POST['profileName']))
{
    getUserData();
}
elseif(isset($_POST['newProfileName']))
{
    createNewUser();
}
else {echo "why god why?";}

function getUserData()
{
    $login = $_POST['profileName'];
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT idUser FROM user WHERE name = '$login'");
}



?>
```

I'll keep picking at it, but if anyone knows the root of this problem please let me know, and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If it's any consolation whatsoever, I had the exact same issue a year or two back, checked the .ini for enabled sqlite extension, etc, nothing worked. But I'll look around for it. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788853/call-to-undefined-function-sqlite-open for starteers.

Comment: @user2356315 Thanks. I'll keep looking for more info, but at this point I'm genuinely just stumped.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @LeviMorrison 5.5.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite extension was removed from PHP source as of version 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.removed-extensions.php

Note that the sqlite3 extension should be used instead. Here's an example of using it:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');

$db->exec('CREATE TABLE foo (bar STRING)');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('This is a test')");

$result = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
?>
```

Comment: I see. My database was made in sqlite manager addon for firefox because I couldn't get other managers to function. The extension is still .sqlite, but some said that can still be an sqlite3 file. Is there some way to tell which one I'm using possibly?

Comment: Thank you for the help. That got rid of that error, but now I'm at a new one that states $db is an undefined variable, which I assume is from my databases extension being .sqlite, so I guess I'll need to find a way to change it. I also have another error that says'Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object', but I'll tackle that after this I suppose.

Comment: Update: Attempted to change YSP_db.sqlite to .db, but the error still persists. Not sure if that was something I could actually do or not without a converter or something.